# Should I suggest blocking Arqade at my workplace?

Tags: ethics, websites

My workplace has a filter for blocking non-work related websites. Thankfully, the filter is lenient enough that I have not come across any instances where a work-necessary resource has been blocked.

For me personally, having access to sites like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), and [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) has been very helpful for productivity. However, I cannot say the same for entertainment sites such as [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), and [Science Fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), which seem to have slipped by unblocked.

**If I see a non-work related site that seems to have "slipped by" our workplace's web filter, am I obligated to report it?**

To clarify, I am ***not*** asking [whether or not these sites ***should*** or ***should not*** be blocked](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/should-we-ban-facebook-or-any-other-social-network-at-workplace). Rather, I am asking whether or not I should mention these sites to a higher-up when I see them.

Comment: What is your position? Is your job tied to IT security or HR or productivity? If not, leave it be.

Comment: *,am I obligated to report it?*  - Why would you think you would be obligated?

Comment: Might as well block all news sites, sports sites, hobby sites... the list goes on.  OR you can just acknowledge that sometimes people de-stress and relax a moment by looking up things they are interested in, and for many people those things involve games/movies/sci-fi.

Comment: I was leaning towards not saying anything, but I wasn't 100% confident before asking. This was very helpful advice!

Comment: "I am not asking whether or not these sites should or should not be blocked" - then you are asking about your workplace policy specifically, which is not answerable by us.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to read any of the unblocked sites, don't - just concentrate on your work instead. (Assuming you're not working in IT / HR, but then you'd probably know if monitoring unblocked sites is part of your job or not).

Your IT department monitors internet traffic and will notice if any particular site is a problem and they'll act on it.

It's likely not part of your job to keep track of what sites are blocked or not and you don't need to report it. Additionally, whatever sites you do visit, use common sense - a porn site may not be blocked (due to whatever reasons) but you should not interpret that as a sign that an employee can visit it at work.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have an employee handbook? Does it say you are obligated to report non-conformant sites to anyone?

If the answer to either of these questions is "no" and you are not in charge of the filter, then just ignore it.